# Print Dialog: How can I remove the Page Range -> Pages default of "0"?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdialog

If I create a simple WinForms PrintDialog as such:

```
PrintDialog print_dialog = new PrintDialog();
print_dialog.UseEXDialog = true;

// Setup dialog defaults
print_dialog.AllowSomePages = true;    // Setting this shows a default value of "0"
print_dialog.AllowCurrentPage = true;
print_dialog.AllowSelection = false;

if (print_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Printing");
}
```

I get the following result, where the Page Range -> Pages has a default value of "0" (circled):

[image: PrintDialog with Page Range 0]

To me that looks unprofessional. Every other program I've looked at has that value blank until it is filled in by the user. Is there anything I can do to make the default show as blank?

Even if I try to hack this by attempting to set the value manually to something that might make more sense to my users than *Pages: 0*, such as:

```
print_dialog.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
```

I get an exception: *Value FromPage is out of range.*

What can I do?

Comment: You should also set this property PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages before you set frompage property

Comment: @lyz Setting `print_dialog.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages` is not compulsory, it just sets 'Pages:' radio button selected. The error is because the specified value is out of range and it's just because the OP didn't set `print_dialog.PrinterSettings.ToPage` value and it uses its default value which is 0. The `FromPage` should be less than or equals to `ToPage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify both `FromPage` and `ToPage` values:

```
//To show 1 in front of Pages:
print_dialog.AllowSomePages = true;  
//Default value for PrinterSettings.MinimumPage is 0
//Default value for PrinterSettings.MaximumPage is 9999
print_dialog.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
print_dialog.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1;
```

The `FromPage` value should be less than or equals to the `ToPage`.

Also both values should be in range specified by `MinimumPage` and `MaximumPage`.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about applying the answer :)

Comment: Thank you Reza.  How strange that you need to specify both to avoid such an enigmatic error, but that does work!  At least I can set it to something sensible. No way to set it to blank?

Comment: You're welcome :) Since the property is `int` you should set it to an integer. Have you ever seen it to be empty in a print dialog? I've never seen. Have you?

Comment: Hmmm... no indeed I haven't! You are right (once again! :). I looked at a lot of print dialog boxes in a lot of programs, and those that had a blank Pages field were actually subtly (or very) different from the .NET PrintDialog, while those that were identical did not have a blank field. So I didn't actually look closely enough, it seems.  Cheers! :)